# dynamically create an array Class in Java

Tags: java, reflection

I am trying to write this function:

```
public static Class arrayTypeFor(Class elementType)
{
     // ... implementation ???
}
```

Usage:

```
arrayTypeFor(int.class); // this should return a Class which is equal to int[].class
```

How do I do this?

I thought about doing this (but it looks pretty inefficient to me).

```
Array.newInstance(elementCType, 1).getClass();
```

Comment: I think you're looking for [Java Generics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html)

Comment: Maybe this will be useful for you? Your are possibly interested in Class.forName(className) method http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html. Something like Class.forName(elementType.class.getName() + "[]");

Comment: yeah, I know these basics on Generics and stuff. But that stilldoesn't help much!

Comment: Why would you want something like this to begin with? Your *pretty inefficient* code works, use it until it proves it is a problem in your design.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I don't think I need to create an entire new object just to get its class.

Comment: @ShibaSoft I belive you are confused between "class" and the Class object!